# Can I query ejabberd database for online users

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 16.03, I would like to query the database to get online users that are shown in admin panel.

Can someone help me? Which table do I have to query?

I think I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM lasts WHERE
```

I need this to make a join with another table of external database. thanks for the help!

Comment: what are you using for session management? Is it default mnesia or anything else? & Please elaborate your exact query i.e what exactly u wish to retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

select * from sm

for odbc as backend

Answer (score 1):

you can get online  users from mnesia database or whatever database you configure such as redis etc if  ejabberd configuration  auth method is internal e.g.-

```
auth_method: internal  //you can find it in ejabberd.yml
```

if ejabberd auth method is 
odbc you can query from database (sm table where current session process id get stored if user id is exist in sm table means user is online) that you have configured. for more detail visit [ejabberd authentication config docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#authentication)

Comment: you can not get online users from ODBC backend because there is no table for that.

Comment: there is sm table  where current session (process id) get stored.